# How to provide value and get a Key back

Tags: erlang

So I have made 2 databases:

1. Db1 that contains: `[{james,london}]`
2. Db2 that contains: `[{james,london},{fredrik,berlin},{fred,berlin}]`

I have a match function that looks like this:

```
match(Element, Db) -> proplists:lookup_all(Element, Db).
```

When I do: `match(berlin, Db2)` I get: `[ ]`

What I am trying to get is a way to input the value and get back the keys in this way: `[fredrik,fred]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to documentation `proplists:lookup_all` works other way:

```
Returns the list of all entries associated with Key in List.
```

So, you can lookup only by keys:

```
(kilter@127.0.0.1)1> Db = [{james,london},{fredrik,berlin},{fred,berlin}].
[{james,london},{fredrik,berlin},{fred,berlin}]
(kilter@127.0.0.1)2> proplists:lookup_all(berlin, Db). 
[]
(kilter@127.0.0.1)3> proplists:lookup_all(fredrik, Db).
[{fredrik,berlin}]
```

You can use `lists:filter` and `lists:map` instead:

```
(kilter@127.0.0.1)7> lists:filter(fun ({K, V}) -> V =:= berlin end, Db).       
[{fredrik,berlin},{fred,berlin}]
(kilter@127.0.0.1)8> lists:map(fun ({K,V}) -> K end, lists:filter(fun ({K, V}) -> V =:= berlin end, Db)).
[fredrik,fred]
```

So, finally

```
match(Element, Db) -> lists:map(
    fun ({K,V}) -> K end, 
    lists:filter(fun ({K, V}) -> V =:= Element end, Db)
).
```

Comment: Alright I understand now. I didn't know that I could use the lists:filter while having a tuple in a list. Thanks a lot for your fast and clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

`proplists:lookup_all/2` takes as a first argument a key; in your example, `berlin` is a value and it's not a key therefore an empty list is returned.

Naturally, you can use recursion and find all the elements (meaning that you will use it like an ordinary list and not a proplist).

Another solution is to change the encoding scheme:

```
[{london,james},{berlin,fredrik},{berlin,fred}]
```

and then use `proplists:lookup_all/2`

The correct way to encode it depends on the way you will access the data (what kind of "queries" you will perform most); but unless you manipulate large amounts of data (in which case you might want to use some other [datastructure](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#key-value-stores)) it isn't really worth analyzing.